# Looking for a PHP smart format number

Tags: php, formatting, numbers

I am looking for a solution for a smart number formatting in PHP.

For example we have 2 numbers below and we need 4 digits after decimal:

```
1.12345678
0.00002345678
```

Using normal number formatting, here are the results:

```
1.1234 // Looking good
0.0000 // No good
```

Can we make it keep going until there are 4 non-zero digits? If it can return 0.00002345, perfect!!!

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While we're glad to help when you're stuck, you're still expected to make an effort of your own to reach the solution. If you've tried something, please [edit] your question to show your attempt and explain where and how it fails to do what you want. And since you're new, I'd recommend reading [ask] for pointers about writing a good question.

Comment: Would it return `0.00002345` or `0.00002346`? Seems the latter since the next digit is a `6` and you'd be losing less information if you performed rounding.

Comment: @ChrisHaas: You're absolutely right about the rounding! Thanks!

Comment: @El_Vanja : Thanks for your comment. In fact I've searched all around but couldn't find the exact answer for my need. I guess not many people want to do this as the result I can't really find something similar.

Comment: I'm sure that [NumberFormatter](https://www.php.net/NumberFormatter) has the appropriate tools to accomplish this, but documentation is terrible.

Answer (score 1):

Might be overkill and the pattern could be optimized, but for fun; get optional 0s AND 4 NOT 0s after the `.`:

```
preg_match('/\d+\.([0]+)?[^0]{4}/', $num, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

To round it we can get 5 digits after the 0s and then format it to the length of that -1 (which will round):

```
preg_match('/\d+\.([0]+?[^0]{5})/', $num, $match);
echo number_format($match[0], strlen($match[1])-1);
```

For `$num = '1234.000023456777';` the result will be `1,234.00002346` and the `$matches` will contain:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1234.000023456
    [1] => 000023456
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your code works great!!! As @ChrisHaas mentioned above, we should round the number, for example: 0.00002345678 should be 0.00002346, can we do that?

Comment: What version of php are you guys using? When I run this code I get `2.3456` as the output. I'm using 7.2 fyi

Comment: if you code as $n = 0.00002345678 you will get 2.3456 as the result. I have to code as $n = "0.00002345678", I guess it is a string, not an integer.

Comment: Ah yea makes sense regX is for strings after all.

Comment: I am wonder if we could combine the reg expression with format number so that we can output: 1,234.00002346 ?

Comment: Added the `number_format` to round.  Tested with a couple of numbers.

Comment: I got problem, the above code works great with number format like x.0000xxx but it returns 0 for all other format such as 1.345678

Answer (score 0):

So this is the code I made to slove this:

```php
$num = 0.00002345678;
$num_as_string = number_format($num,PHP_FLOAT_DIG,'.','');
$zeros = strspn($num_as_string, "0", strpos($num_as_string, ".")+1);
echo number_format($num, (4+$zeros), '.', '');
```

It converts the float number to a string, checks how many zeros exist after the decimal point and then does a number format with the extra zeros accounted for.

Note that it may break if your float is too big, you can change `PHP_FLOAT_DIG` to a number larger that may fix that.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I tried your code but it shows 0.0000 :(

Comment: That's interesting. It works for me when I tested it.

Comment: Maybe it's because of the different php server setup I guess

Answer (score 0):

This code works well. Now I want to add something to it. If there are zeros after the displayed number, those zeros will be deleted. For example: 0.00004300 => 0.000043

How do you think this part can be added to the following code?

```
$num = 0.00004300;
$num_as_string = number_format($num,PHP_FLOAT_DIG,'.','');
$zeros = strspn($num_as_string, "0", 
strpos($num_as_string,".")+1);
echo number_format($num, (4+$zeros), '.', '');
```